# Setting up ReactJS in windows 10 giving error

Tags: reactjs, nginx, docker, npm

i am new reactjs. i want to setup for react js in windows 10 when i install react displaying some following error

> npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10240
>       npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "start"
>       npm ERR! node v6.9.5
>       npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
>       npm ERR! path C:\Users\username\package.json
>       npm ERR! code ENOENT
>       npm ERR! errno -4058
>       npm ERR! syscall open
>
> npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\username\package.json'
>       npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\username\package.json'
>       npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
>       npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
>       npm ERR! enoent
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>       npm ERR!     C:\Users\username\npm-debug.log

Answer (score 0):

From the error it seems like that the directory from where you are trying to install `react` using `npm install -S react` doesn't contain `package.json` file. You will need to set up your project with `package.json` to install react in a local directory. To do that, run the command

```
npm init
```

and follow the instructions

In case you want to `install globally`, you can run

```
npm install -g react
```

Answer (score 0):

Run npm install from the same directory as the project's package.json

e.g. if the package.json is at

`C:\users\josh\myproject\package.json`

then you need to run `npm install` from inside the myproject folder